# EVP_UPDATE never returns

Tags: c, lua, openssl

I am doing a rewrite of LuaCrypto to make it run on Lua 5.3 and support SSL 1.1.0. (it's original code runs on Lua 5.1 and supports SSL up to 1.0).
The major source of incompatibility between LuaCrypto and Lua 5.3 was the load mechanism, that suffered a major revision, and I got it working by replacing all functions related to loading the library.
The major source of incompatibility between LuaCrypto and SSL 1.1.0 is the fact that now SSL structs (specialy EVP and HMAC) are opaque, and the compiler no longer knows the inside of those structs or their size.
LibCrypto unfortunately relied on knowing the size of such structures to load them into the Lua state as userdata. The obvious solution then was to rewrite the library so it loaded the EVP and HMAC structures as lightuserdata, and rewrite the garbage collector metamethods to call SSL free/destroy/whatever to rid the memory from those structures when they are no longer needed.
I done that, and it was all fun and games as long as I run the encryption/decryption/digest in one step. Whenever I tried to use EVP incrementally through EVP_UPDATE() function, the machine freezes as this function is called, but not if I try to run the decryption in one step.

Here is the offending code:

```
static HANDLER_EVP *evp_pget(lua_State *L, int i)
{
  if (luaL_checkudata(L, i, LUACRYPTO_EVPNAME) == NULL)
    luaL_typerror(L, i, LUACRYPTO_EVPNAME);
  return lua_touserdata(L, i);
}

void evp_pnew(lua_State *L, HANDLER_EVP *c)
{
  lua_pushlightuserdata(L, c);
  luaL_getmetatable(L, LUACRYPTO_EVPNAME);
  lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
}

static int evp_fnew(lua_State *L)

    {
  HANDLER_EVP *c = NULL;
  const char *s = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
  DIGEST_TYPE type = DIGEST_BY_NAME(s);

  if (IS_DIGEST_INVALID(type)) {
    luaL_argerror(L, 1, "invalid digest type");
    return 0;
  }

    static int evp_update(lua_State *L)
{
  HANDLER_EVP *c = evp_pget(L, 1);
  size_t s_len;
  const char *s = luaL_checklstring(L, 2, &s_len);
  dumpStack(L);
  debug(L, "c=%p, s=\"%s\", s_len=%d", c, s, s_len);
  EVP_UPDATE(c, s, s_len); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
  debug(L, "I AM HERE"); // never run

  lua_settop(L, 1);
  return 1;
}
```

This is the Lua test:

```
 for i, t in ipairs({"sha1", "md5", "sha1", "hmac"}) do
  print("testing " .. t)
  local d
  if (t == "hmac") then
    d = hmac.new("sha1", "luacrypto")
  else
    d = evp.new(t)
  end

  assert(io.input(F))
  print("all", d:digest(io.read("*all")), F, t)

  d:reset()

  assert(io.input(F))

  while true do
   local c = io.read(1)
   if c == nil then break end
   d:update(c)
  end
  print("loop", d:digest(), F, t)
  if (t ~= "hmac") then
    print("again", d:digest(), F, t)
    assert(io.input(F))
    print("alone", hmac.digest("sha1", io.read("*all"), "luacrypto"), F, t);
  else
    assert(io.input(F))
    print("alone", hmac.digest("sha1", io.read("*all"), "luacrypto"), F, t);
  end

  assert(io.input(F))
  d:reset()

  while true do
   local c = io.read(math.random(1, 16))
   if c == nil then break end
   d:update(c)
  end

  report("reset", d:digest(d), F, t)
  report("known", _G[t .. "_KNOWN"], F, t)
  print("")

end
```

and this is the output:

```
testing sha1

TAG:lua_print LINE:141  

c=0xc14a8

TAG:lua_print LINE:141  

all     d6ed6e26ebeb37ba0792ec75a3d0b4dcec279d25           /mtd0/message      sha1

TAG:lua_print LINE:141  

estou aqui

TAG:lua_print LINE:141  

1: userdata

2: "T"



TAG:lua_print LINE:141  

c=0xc14a8, s="T", s_len=1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, I got this one. The problem was not where it seems that it was.
 Apparently, the reset() function was defective for some reason.

This is what I had for reset:

```
static int evp_reset(lua_State *L)
{
#ifdef CRYPTO_OPENSSL
  EVP_MD_CTX_reset(c);
#elif CRYPTO_GCRYPT
  gcry_md_reset(*c);
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

For some reason, `EVP_MD_CTX_reset()` is not doing what the documentation said it does, and it was not cleaning the struct. So I tried to do so manually this way:

```
static int evp_reset(lua_State *L)
{
  HANDLER_EVP *c = evp_pget(L, 1);
#ifdef CRYPTO_OPENSSL
  const EVP_MD *t = EVP_MD_CTX_md(c);
  //EVP_MD_CTX_reset(c);
  EVP_MD_CTX_init(c);
  EVP_DigestInit_ex(c, t, NULL);
#elif CRYPTO_GCRYPT
  gcry_md_reset(*c);
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

This has eliminated the glitch. It seems like a bug in SSL library.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set metatables for light userdata.

You need to box each SSL struct pointer into a (heavy) user data.

Comment: I had no problems setting metatables for light userdata. Perhaps it is a limitation of older versions of lua.

Comment: You've set the same meltable for *all* light userdata values. Only tables and heavy userdata values can have individual metatables.

Comment: That makes no sense... light userdata needs the  __gc metamethod more than any other lua type, since it need to be explicitly dellocated on the C side, while heavy userdata is dellocated automatically whenever it loses all references on the Lua state. If it was a deliberate decision of the Lua developers, it was a very bad call... But no matter, as you have pointed out, there is a way around it.

Comment: You can set a metatable to every objects in Lua (even *number*s), but only a `__gc` method to a *not light* userdata. Read the [Lua 5.4 reference manuall](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html) sections 2.4 and 2.5.3, this is also true for Lua down to 5.1 at least.